# I want to convert binary document in mongodb to string value

Tags: string, mongodb, binary

I want to convert binary file to string c++

```
bsoncxx::types::b_binary binPayload { 
    bsoncxx::binary_sub_type::k_binary, nPayloadSize, pPayload 
};
```

I put my data on MongoDB so result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dad7502562a841c5e4f54b2"), 
  "time" : 0, 
  "payload" : BinData(0,"AAAAAA==") 
}
```

I want to convert BinData to string and I want to show them